# Save Overleaf Compiled PDF Directly to Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

Overleaf provides a way to download a compiled PDF using the Download button in the image (near the Recompile button):

[image]

But is there a way to directly store the generated PDF on Overleaf so it shows up with the main.tex without first downloading it locally?

Comment: Not understood, what exactly do you mean by `to directly store the generated PDF on Overleaf with other project`?

Comment: I clarified the question now

Comment: This is a question for the Overleaf support

Comment: The way saving the PDF you don't download first, clicking the menu button, and changing the PDF Viewer form overleaf viewer to browser is OK.

Comment: This would really be useful indeed, I hope this becomes possible one day.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way that I know of to have the output.pdf of a project within the project itself. But what works is having the output.pdf in *another* project. To accomplish this you can use the "add file" menu. There you go to "add from another project" -> "select output file" and choose the "output.pdf".

[image]

This might be useful if you want to combine a lot of outputs using `pdfpages` or similar.

Hope this helps!