# using pdf image of a standalone .tex in the main document on Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, asymptote

On my computer, *in the same folder*, I create the main document `main.tex` and a figure `disc.tex` - a standalone TikZ/Asymptote code. First run `disc.tex` to get `disc.pdf`, then run `main.tex` (there is `\includegraphics{disc.pdf}` in it). It works as usual. This way helps increasing compilation time, especially when there are a lot of figures in the main document.

[image]

The content of `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{disc.pdf}
\caption{This is my disc}
\label{fig:mydisc}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The content of `disc.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan!50] circle(1) node[red]{unit disc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I do a similar thing on Overleaf? In
[my example project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hdbsxdwkjhnp)
Overleaf did not recognize where the `disc.pdf` is.

[image]

I think this situation is quite common for TeX users on Overleaf, but I have not found suitable answers on texSE yet. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536159/140722) suggested making 2 or more projects, one is for the main document and each others are for each figure, then importing `output.pdf`s (with name changing if necessary) to the main project. This is not so convenient: think each time we repair code of a figure, we need to import again. We write a book of 100 figures, we need one project, not 101 projects, right?

Comment: You are aware that you consistently mispelled `disc` as `dics` in your question, yes?

Comment: @MarkusG. Yes, I have just correct it. However the problem still exists: Overleaf did not recognize pdf output of another tex file in the same project

Comment: Looks like you can set folders in one of the Overleaf menues, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536146/save-overleaf-compiled-pdf-directly-to-overleaf?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MS-SPO I have cited that link in my question. It is not what I ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try using the `standalone` package and `\includestandalone` in `main.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includestandalone{disc}
\caption{This is my disc}
\label{fig:mydisc}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Compiling `main.tex` will then trigger compiling `disc.tex`, produce `disc.pdf`, and use it in `main.tex`.

[image]

You can also download `disc.pdf` from the [generated files list](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files).

Answer (score 3):

overleaf copies the main document to `/compile` and uses `-jobname=output` so everything's called output.pdf and the file is not there when you need it. You can do

[image]

adding

```
\immediate\write18{pdflatex disc}
```

to `main.tex` so it compiles `disc.pdf` in the directory generated for `main` but note that it does this every time so you don't save any time.

You could wrap that in a test to see if `disc.pdf` exists

```
\IfFileExists{disc.pdf}{}{%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex disc}
}
```

Then if you edit disc.pdf you would need to comment out the test temporarily to force a disc.pdf rebuild

Comment: Thanks for your information! it is a bit pity that it can not be done on Overleaf as the way we do on computers