Figure allignment using tikz
I want to draw the following figure using tikz:
I have both graphs drawn in tikz, each with their independent node-positions.
One solution I could think of is to combine them both with some trial and error but I still would have no clue how to get the Implication-Arrow in between them.
Here's the code for the two tikz graphs in a figure:
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Example of the reduction from TEMPORAL FIREFIGHTER on cliques}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
\node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
\node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
\node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
\node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
\node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
\node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
\node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
\end{scope}

\draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
\draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
\draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);
     
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
\node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
\node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
\node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
\node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
\node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
\node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
\node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
\end{scope}

\draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
\draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
\draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);

\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (2);

\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (5);

\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);

\draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (6);

\draw [black, thick, dashed](4) -- (6);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

which looks like this:
Maybe someone can help me out with this

Here is an other way to do it:

compile figures separately using the standalone class
combine them using graphicx

This gives you more independence and control with fewer side effects, compared to "all-tikz-in-one-file".

Main.tex

It will look for fig1.pdf and fig2.pdf
Make sure, you don't exceed \textwidth
the \raisebox lifts the arrow a little bit up

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \caption{Example of the reduction from TEMPORAL FIREFIGHTER on cliques}
 \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{fig1}
    \raisebox{25mm}{$\Longrightarrow$}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{fig2}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}

fig1.tex
I don't see, why you need a scope here.
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
%  \begin{scope}
  [every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
    \node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
    \node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
    \node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
    \node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
    \node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
    \node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
%  \end{scope}

    \draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
    \draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
    \draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
    \draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
    \draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
    \draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);
     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

fig2.tex
I don't see, why you need a scope here.
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\begin{scope}
[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
    \node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
    \node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
    \node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
    \node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
    \node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
    \node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
%\end{scope}

    \draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
    \draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
    \draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
    \draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
    \draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
    \draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);
    
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (6);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (4);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (5);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (2);
    
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (3);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (6);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (4);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (5);
    
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (4);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (6);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (3);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);
    
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (3);
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (6);
    
    \draw [black, thick, dashed](4) -- (6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Hey, I looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536146/save-overleaf-compiled-pdf-directly-to-overleaf?noredirect=1&lq=1, but am still having trouble running separate standalone files in an Overleaf project, where each time I re-run them, their output is updated next time I run the driver file?

@Jasper, not sure if I get you right. Procedure: compile standalone files, then compile main.tex. You can also use package standalone instead, but I never tried that one.

The reason for me asking is that I have a large Overleaf Project which contains a main.tex which inputs a lot of tikz figures. The compilation time is getting excessive, and externalizing tikz doesn't update the figures when I do. Ahhhhhh! I'll just externalize for the time being, andthen re-externalize after updating them! Nevermind.

Together we made it +1 :)

Using the scope environment and the xshift key to shift the second part of the tikz picture:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Example of the reduction from TEMPORAL FIREFIGHTER on cliques}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
  \node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
  \node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
  \node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
  \node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
  \node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
  \node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
  \node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
  \end{scope}
  \draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
  \draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
  \draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
  \draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
  \draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
  \draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);
  \node at (3,-1.25) {$\Longrightarrow$};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
  \node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
  \node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
  \node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
  \node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
  \node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
  \node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
  \node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
  \end{scope}
  
  \draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
  \draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
  \draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
  \draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
  \draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
  \draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);
  
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (6);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (4);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (5);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (2);
  
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (3);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (6);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (4);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (5);
  
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (4);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (6);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (3);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);
  
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (3);
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (6);
  
  \draw [black, thick, dashed](4) -- (6);
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}



Set the baseline to the center of the pictures.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp] % <--- never just h
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
\node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
\node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
\node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
\node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
\node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
\node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
\node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
\end{scope}
\draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
\draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
\draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\qquad$\Longrightarrow$\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
\node (R) at (0,0.25) {r};
\node (1) at (1.5,-0.5) {1};
\node (2) at (1.5,-2) {2};
\node (3) at (-1.5,-0.5) {3};
\node (4) at (-0.75,-3.25) {4};
\node (5) at (0.75,-3.25) {5};
\node (6) at (-1.5,-2) {6};
\end{scope}
\draw [black, thick](R) -- (1);
\draw [black, thick](1) -- (2);
\draw [black, thick](R) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick](4) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick](3) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](R) -- (2);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](1) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (4);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](2) -- (5);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (3);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](5) -- (6);
\draw [black, thick, dashed](4) -- (6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Example of the reduction from TEMPORAL FIREFIGHTER on cliques}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


