No PDF file being saved
Why overleaf is not creating a PDF document every time I compile?
It means it shows a PDF output, but no PDF file is automatically saved in the folder.
I have to download them when I require them, but with different software like TEXMAKER, a PDF file is always saved in the directory.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536146/2388 (I don't know if this is still valid, if needed ask the overleaf support).

The pdf file is built in a build directory, it is not added to your project files, naturally you need to download it to access a copy as it is built on their server not your machine

"with different software like TEXMAKER, a PDF file is always saved in the directory" Not always, locally LyX and  Gummi follow the same approach. You have every preview saved hiddenly somewhere, but not in your  working directory except when you want. This have  some disadvantages, but it have sense do not overwrite your previous with any change but until you  decide that is a good new version.

Actually none of these addresses the original query. The already posted question is identical but the answers are not sufficient.

Well, your question as to why Overleaf behaves this way should be better asked to the Overleaf staff. And this is also stated in the comments of the other question ...

Sure will do. Thanks for the same.
